# grep : how to put the filename before each match, when the file comes from a pipe?

Tags: bash, shell, find, grep, pipe

With this line I get always `Standardinput` as file-name before the matches.
 Is there a way to rewrite this line to get the real file-name in front of the matches?

```
find . -name '*.doc' -exec wvText {} \; | grep -rH --color word
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.doc' | xargs -d"\n" grep -rH --color word
```

Ah, that doesn't handle the `wvText` bit in there.  Maybe something like this instead:

```
for doc in `find . -name '*.doc'`; do wvText "$doc" | grep -rH --color word | \
sed "s;^;$doc: ;"; done
```